# Building VOIP into an application (C++ specifically)

Tags: c++, voip

Are there existing libraries and frameworks which allow VOIP to be built into a bespoke application without reinventing the wheel? A customer is interested by the possibility for a C++ desktop application and while it's not *hugely* useful (they could just use skype), it is quite *cool*.

I believe some technologies like DirectX may have some functionality built in for in-game chat, is that right? What else is there in the form of free/paid 3rd-party libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since Asterisk is open source, that's a good place to start.

Check out [Astxx](http://matt-land.com/astxx/)

"The goal of Astxx is to provide a fully functional and easy to use C++
wrapper for Asterisk enabling developers to write Asterisk related software
using the full range of what C++ has to offer.  This includes AGI scripts
and accessing the Manager API."

Also [IAXClient](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iaxclient/)

"A lightweight cross platform IP telephony client using the IAX protocol, designed for use with the asterisk open source PBX. "

And [Asterisk Sockets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ast-cppsock/)

"Asterisk Manage API and FAGI C++ Framework. Implemented with high efficient OS independent Sockets wrapper (ACE). Provide C++ API wrappers for Asterisk Manager API and FAGI."

There's also a [.NET library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asterisk-dotnet/)

"The Asterisk .NET library consists of a set of C# classes that allow you to easily build applications that interact with an Asterisk PBX Server (1.0/1.2/1.4 version). Both FastAGI and Manager API supported. .NET/Mono compatible."

Comment: Sounds interesting. I never heard of Asterisk though... I can't tell if it's an app users would have to install which Astxx talks to, or a bunch of libs/DLLs that can be included with any project?

Comment: Hmm, see Asterisk is GPL. Is that an issue for writing closed-source apps, I can never remember the details?

Comment: Yes, that is an issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842776/gpl-license-in-closed-source-application

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider some form of SIP client which could be used as a basis for a softphone application.  Check out the free [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) library.

Answer (score 2):

For SIP libraries, you should also look at Sofia-SIP and the GNU oSIP library.

As SIP is only use for session initiation, you'll also need a library for audio streaming (an RTP library).  I've used and recommend [librtp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/librtp/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a Windows C++, vb.NET or C#.Net VOIP app that uses SIP and RTP, check out the LanScape VOIP media engine SDK. Its not just a SIP library or RTP media library – it handles all the VOIP call requirements. This voip sdk is not free or open source. You license it from LS.

We used the LS sdk when we developed our windows VOIP client (softphone) and also use it on our windows voip servers for pstn trunk termination. The v5 sdk they had experienced some bugs but the “Release 6” media engine has worked great for us.

Here’s the link to [their site](http://www.lanscapecorp.com) and to the [LS voip SDK](http://www.lanscapecorp.com/ProductPages/LanScapeVoipMediaEngine.asp).

We have been using the sdk for 3-4 years. The free and paid support LS offers is very good. I also have it on good authority that they are going to offer the same sdk on Linux and Mac OS X snow leopard.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out VDK: http://www.voipdevkit.com It's not free, but it's multi-platform and allows very easy integration of VoIP in other applications. It offers high-level API, so you don't have to deal with SIP or RTP by yourself.